# What's the best generic list of media queries mobile to wqhd?

Tags: css, sass, media-queries

I would like to build an application with support to mobile, tablet, laptop and desktop. I would like this to be generic and not device specific.

So far I have the following queries but they don't seem to work properly for certain ocasions:

```
    $mobile-only: max-width 640px;
    $mobile: min-width 0;
    $mobile-portrait: min-width 0 orientation portrait;
    $mobile-landscape: min-width 0 orientation landscape;
    $tablet-only: min-width 641px max-width 1024px;
    $tablet: min-width 768px;
    $tablet-portrait: min-width 420px max-width 767px orientation portrait;
    $tablet-landscape: min-width 768px orientation landscape;
    $laptop-only: min-width 1025px max-width 1440px;
    $laptop: min-width 1025px;
    $desktop-only: min-width 1441px max-width 1920px;
    $desktop: min-width 1441px;
    $wqhd: min-width 1921px;
```

A use case: http://codepen.io/vinicius5581/pen/reormP

I was wondering if anyone has a good set and if you don't mind sharing, please do so. :)